# Build other projects post-build action missing Trigger radio buttons

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

I'm running Jenkins version 1.466.12.1 (Jenkins Enterprise 12.11).  With a new job I'm trying to add a post-build action to build other projects, but the expect radio buttons for trigger options isn't there.

I have jobs that were already created that have the following options:

- Trigger only if build succeeds
- Trigger even if the build is unstable
- Trigger even if the build fails

Those options don't exist if I create a new job.  If I copy a job, then those options exist.  I don't recall the version number of the previous Jenkins Enterprise, but it was working then.

I also have a non-enterprise version of Jenkins running on my desktop computer and those Trigger options don't exist on version 1.483.

Did something change with this post-build action?  Maybe I forgot a fancy/useful plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JENKINS-16444](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-16444) was fixed in Jenkins 1.500. The workaround should be to add the build trigger, save the configuration, then go back to the configuration page again and these options should be visible—the problem applies only when first adding the trigger.

Comment: Yes, this is true. You can see those buttons once you save the new job and revisit the configuration page.